# Why does putting a multidimensional array in varargs cause a compiler warning?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, parameter-passing, compiler-warnings, variadic-functions

I have a very simple not null checker that has a varargs parameter of type Object

`public static void nonNull(Object... objects) {
    //...
}`

When I call it with a multidimensional array of any type, like:

```
nonNull(new int[][] {})
```

or

```
nonNull(new Object[][] {})
```

it results in a compiler warning saying "Inexact type match for varargs". it also happens for more than 2 dimensional arrays.

The warning doesn't appear for examples:

```
nonNull(new Object[] {})
```

or

```
nonNull(new Object())
```

I was just curious why. A multidimensional array is just another object just like a regular array isn't it? So why is the type match inexact?

Comment: By the way, Java does provide an [Objects.requireNonNull](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#requireNonNull-T-java.lang.String-) method.  Three of them, in fact.

Comment: yeah i know but i made a version of that for passing object arrays instead of individual objects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you provide a single `Object[]` to your varargs method, it will be used as the `objects` argument directly rather than being wrapped in a length-1 array.

Both `new int[][]{}` and `new Object[][]{}` technically **count as being of type `Object[]`**, due to array covariance.

Thus, for both `nonNull(new int[][] {})` and `nonNull(new Object[][] {})`, the array you provided will be used as `objects` directly, rather than being passed as the sole element of a length-1 `Object[]`.

It's pretty likely that you didn't want that to happen, so Java is giving you a warning about it.

Comment: ohh i think i get it! So if i pass in an int[][] method, the nested int arrays inside the int array are passed in instead of the actual int[][] object?